# Response is not available in this context asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I am developing an asp.net web application. Response.Redirect is throwing exception "Response is not available in this context asp.net".

There are 2 cases:

CASE1: When I use response.redirect directly from default.aspx page

```
If(certain Condition) //This runs perfectly fine
{
     Session["UserId"] = intUserId;
     Session["SessionId"] = intSessionId;
     Session["Password"] = strPassword;
     Session["IsLoggedIn"] = Global.objOmniFlow.IsLoggedIn;
     Session["LastLogin"] = strLastLoginTime;
     Response.Redirect(CPCHostURL + QueryString);
}
```

CASE2: The control goes from default.aspx.cs to a javascript function from there to asp handler page then again back to default.aspx.cs after that the response.redirect calls throws exception:

```
     Session["UserId"] = intUserId;
     Session["SessionId"] = intSessionId;
     Session["Password"] = strPassword;
     Session["IsLoggedIn"] = Global.objOmniFlow.IsLoggedIn;
     Session["LastLogin"] = strLastLoginTime;
     Response.Redirect(CPCHostURL + QueryString);//Exception here Response is not available in this context asp.net
```

The javascript function is called in default.aspx.cs file and function is

```
 function abc()
      {

          var userName = '<%=Session["UserName"]%>';
          var cabinetName = '<%=Session["CabinetName"]%>';
          var moduleName = '<%=Session["ModuleName"]%>';
          var clearingType = '<%=Session["clearingType"]%>'; 
          var caseFlagtwo = '2';
          var oldPassword=  $("#pwd1").val()
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "LoginHandler1.ashx?userName=" + userName + "&cabinetName=" + cabinetName + "&moduleName=" + moduleName + "&oldPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(oldPassword) + "&caseFlag=" + caseFlagtwo + "&clearingType=" + clearingType,
              //data: {serviceIndex:serviceIndex, serviceStatus: serviceStatus, action: action },
              // dataType: "json",  
              success: function (outputString) {
                  alert(outputString);

              },
              error: function (outputString) {
                  // var result = json.name;
              }
          });
      }
```

The ashx file which recieves this is:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        String userName = context.Request["userName"].ToString();
        String cabinetName = context.Request["cabinetName"].ToString();
        String moduleName = context.Request["moduleName"].ToString();
        String caseFlag = context.Request["caseFlag"].ToString();
        String clearingType = context.Request["clearingType"].ToString();


            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Default obj = new Default();
            obj.ForceLogin(userName, cabinetName, moduleName, clearingType);
        }
```

Force login is the function in which I am using response.redirect.

NOTE: When instead of Response.Redirect I am using

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(CPCHostURL + QueryString);
```

then no exception is coming but I am not redirected to the specified url instead the control remains on the same page from where I am sending the response redirect

Note: CPCHostURL = http://192.168.56.210/CPCHost/

Complete URL =  http://192.168.56.210/CPCHost/?UserName=admin&Password=admin123&UserIndex=1&SessionId=934425343&Cabinet=maincab&LastLoginAt=2017-01-02 15:03:34&ClearingType=ok

Comment: problem is in your complete url  before "?" there should not be "/"

Comment: @ManishGoswami The URL is correct as I have already told that in case 1 it is working perfectly fine with the same URL. So I think problem is something else

Comment: As it stands, this question cannot really be answered. You need to show the `javascript`, *how* control *goes to a javascript function* what code is in the `ashx` handler and how control goes back to default.aspx.

Comment: @user1429080 I have updated the detail. See if you can find out what I am doing wrong. DO tell in case of any more confusion in question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear because of missing data, but as far i can see the response redirect should work.

My suspicion is your generated url, which seems in wrong format.

if  CPCHostURL = http://192.168.56.210/CPCHost/ then you concat the query string directly afterwards which normally might result with http://192.168.56.210/CPCHost/?id=232&etc=232 which is not valid url.

Post your generated url for a possibly better answer.

Comment: As i suspected your URL seems wrong, if you manually paste that url to a browser , do you get the result you want ?

Comment: The URL is correct as I have already told that in case 1 it is working perfectly fine with the same URL. So I think problem is something else